# display photo or video from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there some kind of a plugin to display a photo or video from a website link like if you post a link on Facebook it loads a miniature picture of the link?

Answer (score 1):

This is called URL Scraping.  What you would need to do is load the URL and look at the content of the HTML that is returned.  From that the scraper would decide what images, and information are best suited for a "preview".

Usually scrapers would look at the pages meta data embedded within `<meta>` tags.

A great example (and how Facebook does it) is the Open Graph protocol.  You can read more about it here - http://ogp.me/

Here is an example of what Open Graph meta tags look like -

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
```

When you post a link on Facebook, it will go out and look for meta tags like these and use their information to display a preview of the link.

Comment: is there a plugin so I can use that information on my website with javascript?

Comment: I don't know of any JavaScript implementations.  Maybe [@Dear's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10963288/558021) will be helpful there.  My answer was to explain more or less how it works.

Comment: is that the client side functionality you described?

Comment: No functionality in my post.  All I was doing was explaining what the concept of URL scraping is.

Comment: ok. thanks for the explanation! Do you know some plugins which do that on the client side? Dear provided a tool which works with node.js and I don't have it. Do I need xhr for that functionality?

Comment: I think you need to do a little bit more research on this topic.  I'm not going to search Google for a plugin that you requested...

Comment: Maybe you should consider a non-client side scraper that will simply return its results via AJAX to the client side?

Comment: i only use the openfire xmpp (jabber) server so far. do you think it is necessary to add a new server for that?

Comment: I don't know about what kind of server you are talking about.. But if you are able to write some serverside scripts on your server, you don't need an additional server.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for spider : https://github.com/mikeal/spider ( or something like that google it )
and please read what @lix has said .

Comment: I don't use node.js on the server side. I just use the openfire server. Do I need node.js or some other server side code for the functionality I need? The app will be packaged with phonegap for mobile devices, so it should work on mobile browsers, too.

Comment: it depends on your server . if your server if capable to run spider,then dont use any other server   . Yes,you need a lot more things to achieve this functionality.